# Laravel Sometimes Showing 404 not found page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm working on **Laravel 8** and i have a problem **sometimes** when I *refresh page or open it direct* by link showing

**Not found page 404 error** , i tried  lots of solutions on internet but no solution working with me .

Another note : it's also showing for me when i send request using **ajax** it's the most time showed for me .

My **web.php** :

```
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

$adminPathName = env('ADMIN_PATH');

Route::get($adminPathName . '/test/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    session('lang', 'en');

    app()->setLocale($locale);
    echo App::getLocale();
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('frontend.home');
});

$adminPathName = env('ADMIN_PATH');
$userPath = env('USER_PATH');

Route::get($adminPathName . '/login', 'Admin\LoginController@login');
Route::post($adminPathName . '/signin', 'Admin\LoginController@signin');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['AdminAuth']], function () {
    $adminPathName = env('ADMIN_PATH');
    Route::get($adminPathName . '/dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@home');
    Route::get($adminPathName . '/languages/manage-languages', 'Admin\LanguageController@index');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/add-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@addLanguage');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/add-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@addTranslate');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/update-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@updateTranslate');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/remove-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@removeTranslate');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/remove-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@removeLanguage');
    Route::post($adminPathName . '/languages/sync-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@syncLanguage');
    Route::get($adminPathName . '/languages/translate/{langId}', 'Admin\LanguageController@translateById');
});


// todo this route should be added below .
Route::get('/login/facebook/callback', 'User\LoginController@facebookCallback');

Route::group(['prefix' => '/{locale}', 'middleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class, 'as' => 'locale'], function () {

    $userPath = env('USER_PATH');

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('frontend.home');
    });
    Route::get($userPath . '/login', 'User\LoginController@login');
    Route::post($userPath . '/signin', 'User\LoginController@signin');
    Route::get($userPath . '/create-account', 'User\UserController@createAccount');
    Route::post($userPath . '/complete-register', 'User\UserController@completeRegister');

    /* Facebook Login & Register  */

    Route::get($userPath . '/social/facebook/redirect', 'User\LoginController@facebookRedirect');
    /* ./ Facebook Login & Register  */

    /* Google Login & Register  */
    Route::get($userPath . '/social/google/redirect', 'User\LoginController@googleRedirect');
    Route::get($userPath . '/social/google/callback', 'User\LoginController@googleCallback');
    /* ./ Google Login & Register  */

    Route::get('/change-language/{lang}', 'User\WebSiteController@changeLanguage');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['UserAuth']], function () {
        $userPath = env('USER_PATH');
        Route::get($userPath . '/dashboard', 'User\UserController@dashboard');
        Route::get($userPath . '/update-profile', 'User\UserController@userProfile');
        Route::get($userPath . '/website/create-website', 'User\WebSiteController@newWebsite');
        Route::post($userPath . '/card/upload-gallery', 'User\UserController@uploadGallery');
        Route::get($userPath . '/cards/new-card/{card_lang}', 'User\CardController@newCard');
        Route::get($userPath . '/cards/new-card/{card_lang}/{card_key}', 'User\CardController@newCard');
        Route::post($userPath . '/cards/get-card-gallery', 'User\CardController@getGalleryByCardId');
        Route::post($userPath . '/cards/update-card', 'User\CardController@updateCard');
        Route::post($userPath . '/cards/update-card-logo', 'User\CardController@updateCardLogo');

        Route::get($userPath . '/logout', function () {
            auth('UserAuth')->logout();
            return redirect(ulocale_path('/login'));
        });
    });


});


Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/{id}/card', 'User\CardController@shoBusinessCardById');
});
```

And **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #Session timeout

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php


</IfModule>
```

The most time it's error showing in the below route :

```
 Route::post($userPath . '/cards/get-card-gallery', 'User\CardController@getGalleryByCardId');
```

Controller Side `getGalleryByCardId` :

```
public function getGalleryByCardId(Request $request)
{
    $imgs = DB::table('card_docs')
        ->where('user_id', usession('user_id'))
        ->where('card_key', $request->card_key)->get();

    return $imgs;
}
```

Comment: sometimes Errors are very hard to debug. havent you find any sequences which make it 404? on the 404 error, if you refresh the page, what will you get? is it 404 again?

Comment: please share the action code for action CardController@getGalleryByCardId

Comment: Probably when `env()` calls in the routes may be the issue. Why don't you try to set the values required in a config file. That ways the values will be cached with other config values. Another thing is why not use Route::prefix() instead of using the variable on each route

Comment: Not using env() calls in routes, using route prefix, caching routes and config should most likely solve the issue you have at hand. When Laravel tries to read .env via DotEnv & faces any issue, it doesn't error out while bootstrapping (some old threads L5.2 days) which would mean when routes are being read (w/o caching) your env() calls return null so the route urls change and hence 404 error - my thoughts

Comment: Intermittently when you get the 404 errors do you also see database or encryption related errors in the log - if yes then it's most probably the .env file not being read or delay in reading.

Comment: @Abilogos thank you to your comment , i will try but this problem sometimes occur one time at day , if it's not occurred with me i will ask you to put this comment as answer .

Comment: @Donkarnash actually i'm not a professional in Laravel how can put it in config file ? can you explain that for me ?

Comment: @AbdAbughazaleh please share the action code for action CardController@getGalleryByCardId

Comment: @OMR , i did you can check question again .

Comment: please share url, where you get 404 error.

Answer (score 5):

From what you describe, I feel that `env()` calls in your route file can be the issue.

When Laravel is not able to read environment values from `.env` file due to time lag in loading or any other issue it doesn't give any error related to environment variables not available, but continues processing.

Since your route files uses `env()` to get values from `.env` non availability of those values change the url of your routes hence you may get 404 error.

like `$userPath = env('USER_PATH')` and `$adminPath = env('ADMIN_PATH')` will result in values for both $userPath and $adminPath being null if there's issue is loading environment variables but execution will continue.

So where ever in urls these variables are used those urls will change with null as value where ever the variables are used

You can check the error logs when you get 404: if they have any entries for database or encryption related errors - it most likely is due to DotEnv not able to read from `.env` on time

> @Donkarnash actually i'm not a professional in Laravel how can put it in config file ? can you explain that for me ?

You can create a new file at `config/custom.php` name whatever you like instead of `custom.php`

```php
return [
    'userPath' => env('USER_PATH'),
    
    'adminPath' => env('ADMIN_PATH'),
];
```

Then you can make changes in your route file to use these values with `config()` helper

```php
Route::get(config('custom.adminPath') . '/login', 'Admin\LoginController@login');
Route::post(config('custom.adminPath') . '/signin', 'Admin\LoginController@signin');
Route::prefix(config('custom.adminPath'))
    ->middleware(['AdminAuth'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@home');
        Route::get('/languages/manage-languages', 'Admin\LanguageController@index');
        Route::post('/languages/add-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@addLanguage');
        Route::post('/languages/add-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@addTranslate');
        Route::post('/languages/update-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@updateTranslate');
        Route::post('/languages/remove-translate', 'Admin\LanguageController@removeTranslate');
        Route::post('/languages/remove-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@removeLanguage');
        Route::post('/languages/sync-language', 'Admin\LanguageController@syncLanguage');
        Route::get('/languages/translate/{langId}', 'Admin\LanguageController@translateById');
    });

// todo this route should be added below .
Route::get('/login/facebook/callback', 'User\LoginController@facebookCallback');

Route::prefix('/{locale}/' . config('custom.userPAth'))
    ->middleware([\App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class])
    ->as('locale')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('frontend.home');
        });
        Route::get('/login', 'User\LoginController@login');
        Route::post('/signin', 'User\LoginController@signin');
        Route::get('/create-account', 'User\UserController@createAccount');
        Route::post('/complete-register', 'User\UserController@completeRegister');
        /* Facebook Login & Register  */

        Route::get('/social/facebook/redirect', 'User\LoginController@facebookRedirect');
        /* ./ Facebook Login & Register  */

        /* Google Login & Register  */
        Route::get('/social/google/redirect', 'User\LoginController@googleRedirect');
        Route::get('/social/google/callback', 'User\LoginController@googleCallback');

        Route::get('/change-language/{lang}', 'User\WebSiteController@changeLanguage');
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['UserAuth']], function () {
            Route::get('/dashboard', 'User\UserController@dashboard');
            Route::get('/update-profile', 'User\UserController@userProfile');
            Route::get('/website/create-website', 'User\WebSiteController@newWebsite');
            Route::post('/card/upload-gallery', 'User\UserController@uploadGallery');
            Route::get('/cards/new-card/{card_lang}', 'User\CardController@newCard');
            Route::get('/cards/new-card/{card_lang}/{card_key}', 'User\CardController@newCard');
            Route::post('/cards/get-card-gallery', 'User\CardController@getGalleryByCardId');
            Route::post('/cards/update-card', 'User\CardController@updateCard');
            Route::post('/cards/update-card-logo', 'User\CardController@updateCardLogo');

            Route::get('/logout', function () {
                auth('UserAuth')->logout();

                return redirect(ulocale_path('/login'));
            });
        });
    });

Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/{id}/card', 'User\CardController@shoBusinessCardById');
});
```

By using values from config instead of env, you can get a benefit by config caching.

In production you can also mitigate the routing url related issue by caching routes - but for that you will need to convert the closure based routes to controller based routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you get **404** *and* you are using **mcamara/laravel-localization** then you *can* delete the contents of bootstrap/cache (the files only). I tried that and got some other issues everytime the cache was cleared and could not figure out why.
Turns out that if you use mcamara/laravel-localization to translate routes etc you can't use "php artisan optimize", because you have localized routes.

So you need to use

```
php artisan route:trans:cache
php artisan route:trans:clear
```

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/CACHING.md

This took me many hours to find so leaving it here if anyone else fights the same issue.